# C++ Struct Array Win Form corruption

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Been stuck on this all day.The data in statsStruct becomes corrupt very first second the program starts in main at line 1. I do not know why when ever I try to declare statsStruct as global it becomes this way.
EDIT: This does compile just the values are all messed up in statsstruct, text is corrupted and value is 323232

```
extern attributes statsStruct[];
```

statsStruct is extern in header file for multiple cpp but Iv deleted all source code till just statsSTruct remains but I cannot get it to be global. When i declare it inside a function it works with good values but I need it global across multiple files and have it share same value.

```
 // tess.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include "test.h"
using namespace tess;
struct attributes{
   std::string stat;
   int amount;  
};  
attributes statsStruct[] = {{"Acc",0},
                        {"Cri",0},
                        {"Cr",0},
                        {"Crit",0},
                        {"Cr",0},
                        {"Ev",0},
                        {"An",0}};

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
   // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
   Application::EnableVisualStyles();
   Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

   // Create the main window and run it
   Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should indicate how you can tell that the array is corrupted. It might be that your code to read the array is wrong.

Comment: Stepping through it with debugger, breakpoint at first point in main and look at it. I have also looked at it in functions that are suppose to use it and it has gone wrong there as well so I believe its way its being declared maybe? new to this win form stuff. Code has zero problems without interface code.

Comment: Seems know one knows :(

Comment: Why do you use native types in CLR application?

Comment: because rest of application was coded with these types before interface.

Comment: I erased everything now and just made a global wstring = "sdfkldfs" and i get some crazy symbols. Seems anything I try to make global messes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got a repro for this, rather by accident.  It is caused by a compiler setting in your project.  To fix it, right-click your project in the Solution Explorer window, Properties, General.  Change the Common Language Runtime support setting from `/clr:pure` to `/clr`

I need to wave my hands a bit at the explanation.  With /clr:pure in effect, the compiler is only allowed to generate pure IL and no machine code.  Problem is, the CLR does *not* support global variables.  The compiler has to pull a few stunts to emulate your attributes[] array, an unmanaged array, and get it initialized properly.  This appears to be enough to confuse the debugger, it takes you to the shim for "statsArray" instead of the actual statsArray data.  You'll indeed see garbage in the array elements.  An extra pointer dereference is required, and then some, the debugger forgets to do this.

Always compile with `/clr` in effect if you use unmanaged declarations.

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me crazy wasted days on this. It works :)