# C++ Winform CLRGlobal Struct

Tags: c++, clr

I am struggling in trying to convert my console application to winform. I just need this struct to be global, but when I declare it in global way it the value is corrupt.

```
struct attributes{
std::string stat;
int amount;  
};  
attributes statsStruct[] = {{"Acc",0},
                    {"Cri",0},
                    {"Cr",0},
                    {"Crit",0},
                    {"Cr",0},
                    {"Ev",0},
                    {"An",0}};
```

That's all, just need to make this global for my application to work, but its proving to be complicated. Does not matter if I put extern or header files or make it a class. I just cannot get this to be global. It does compile but values are wrong which I find hard to believe since I just set declared it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Struct Array Win Form corruption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028140/c-struct-array-win-form-corruption)

Comment: Do not ask the same question repeatedly, you have to be patient on a Sunday.